# How to Compile Bootstrap Theme Scss Files in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, npm, sass

I have bit knowledge about how to compile scss file using `npm run dev`. 
But now I have Bootstrap html theme folder where all assets files are included like scss and css . i am confused that is i have to `@import` all bootstrap theme folder scss files name in laravel `app.scss` file for compile or just copy Bootstrap theme folder scss files and paste on laravel `assets/scss` folder and run command `npm run dev`. please help thanks

Comment: Your theme will have an “entry” file (i.e. **theme.scss**). Simply `@import` this in your **resources/sass/app.scss** file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your resources/sass/app.scss file or any other file you want to have the theme files included, add the following line of code

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

This line of code includes all bootstrap scss files that can be found in the node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap folder. If you have a custom directory for your scss files you can include them like this

```
@import 'custom_folder/bootstrap-saa/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

Do not forget to add the entry into your webpack.mix.js file in your root folder.

```
mix.sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```